# Is there a "Facebook access token debugger" like tool for Google and/or other OAuth providers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Preferably something that shows the expiration time and authorized resources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground to inspect the steps in the auth dance. Click the settings icon to change the authorization URL to Facebook's for example.

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: That's more of a console, rather than an access token debugger, isn't it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "token debugger" then? Google has an endpoint to check the status of an access token: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken but I don't believe this is part of the OAuth 2.0 spec, and I don't believe Facebook or Twitter has one.

Comment: Like this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, but that endpoint works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Basically the equivalent of fb's debugtoken is the GET call: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=

More on that here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: the endpoint is now `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=` more on that here: `https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth`